# Notify app.js if it run from "npm run dev" or "npm start"

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Is that possible to notify app.js file or any other file that I am using a specific script from package.json?
my relevant scripts

```
"dev":"nodemon app.js",
"start":"node app.js"
```

In my case i have cron functions that run on background,  its a problem when I using nodemon and some of those function invoked  I kill them before them ended.

on other way , its more convenient to use nodemon on development, so i want to know if there is a way to notify my app.js if it run from "npm start" or "npm run dev"

Comment: Your approach is not correct. The application must not know anything about who starts it. Use different configuration files for the two cases: production (`npm start`) and development/debug (`npm run dev`) and pass the name of the configuration to use either as a command line argument or (better) in an environment variable. The standard environment variable `NODE_ENV` is usually used to tell apart these situation. Its values would be `production` and `development`. https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/nodejs-the-difference-between-development-and-production/

Comment: im not sure i understand you, can u explain more with example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using arguments ?

```
"dev":"nodemon app.js dev",
"start":"node app.js production"
```

`process.argv` holds a list of all arguments, including `dev` and `production` now which can then be used to distinguish the two cases.